# How to convert escape characters in HTML tags?

Tags: html, string, go, escaping, html-escape-characters

How can we directly convert `"\u003chtml\u003e"` to `"<html>"`? Conversion of `"<html>"` to `"\u003chtml\u003e"` is quite easy using `json.Marshal()`, but `json.Unmarshal()` is quite lengthy and cumbersome. Is there any direct way to do that in golang?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`strconv.Unquote()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Unquote) to do the conversion.

One thing you should be aware of is that `strconv.Unquote()` can only unquote strings that are in quotes (e.g. start and end with a quote char `"` or a back quote char `` ` ``),  so we have to manually append that.

Example:

```
// Important to use backtick ` (raw string literal)
// else the compiler will unquote it (interpreted string literal)!

s := `\u003chtml\u003e`
fmt.Println(s)
s2, err := strconv.Unquote(`"` + s + `"`)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(s2)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/e9UOovTYN-)):

```
\u003chtml\u003e
<html>
```

---

**Note:** To do HTML text escaping and unescaping, you can use the [`html`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/) package. Quoting its doc:

> Package html provides functions for escaping and unescaping HTML text.

But the `html` package (specifically [`html.UnescapeString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/#UnescapeString)) does not decode unicode sequences of the form `\uxxxx`, only `&#decimal;` or `&#xHH;`.

Example:

```
fmt.Println(html.UnescapeString(`\u003chtml\u003e`)) // wrong
fmt.Println(html.UnescapeString(`&#60;html&#62;`))   // good
fmt.Println(html.UnescapeString(`&#x3c;html&#x3e;`)) // good
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/bcqJohzYlq)):

```
\u003chtml\u003e
<html>
<html>
```

---

**Note #2:**

You should also note that if you write a code like this:

```
s := "\u003chtml\u003e"
```

This quoted string will be unquoted by the compiler itself as it is an *interpreted string literal*, so you can't really test that. To specify quoted string in the source, you may use the backtick to specify a *raw string literal* or you may use a *double quoted* interpreted string literal:

```
s := "\u003chtml\u003e" // Interpreted string literal (unquoted by the compiler!)
fmt.Println(s)

s2 := `\u003chtml\u003e` // Raw string literal (no unquoting will take place)
fmt.Println(s2)

s3 := "\\u003chtml\\u003e" // Double quoted interpreted string literal
                           // (unquoted by the compiler to be "single" quoted)
fmt.Println(s3)
```

Output:

```
<html>
\u003chtml\u003e
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir! You are awesome! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `fmt` string formatting package for this scope.

```
fmt.Printf("%v","\u003chtml\u003e") // will output <html>
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ZEot6bxO1H

Comment: Actually `"\u003chtml\u003e"` is unquoted by the compiler, not by the `fmt` package. You will see it if you try it with the backtick: `

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a common problem. This is how I get it work.

```
func _UnescapeUnicodeCharactersInJSON(_jsonRaw json.RawMessage) (json.RawMessage, error) {
    str, err := strconv.Unquote(strings.Replace(strconv.Quote(string(_jsonRaw)), `\\u`, `\u`, -1))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return []byte(str), nil
}

func main() {
    // Both are valid JSON.
    var jsonRawEscaped json.RawMessage   // json raw with escaped unicode chars
    var jsonRawUnescaped json.RawMessage // json raw with unescaped unicode chars

    // '\u263a' == '☺'
    jsonRawEscaped = []byte(`{"HelloWorld": "\uC548\uB155, \uC138\uC0C1(\u4E16\u4E0A). \u263a"}`) // "\\u263a"
    jsonRawUnescaped, _ = _UnescapeUnicodeCharactersInJSON(jsonRawEscaped)                        // "☺"

    fmt.Println(string(jsonRawEscaped))   // {"HelloWorld": "\uC548\uB155, \uC138\uC0C1(\u4E16\u4E0A). \u263a"}
    fmt.Println(string(jsonRawUnescaped)) // {"HelloWorld": "안녕, 세상(世上). ☺"}
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/pUsrzrrcDG-

Hope this helps someone.