# How to prevent escaping certain characters in strings produced by JSON encoder?

Tags: json, go, special-characters, stringify

I have a map to save json entries. Here is a preview from my code.

```
mp := map[string]string{"key": "The Knight & Day"}
fmt.Println(mp)
bty3, err := json.Marshal(mp)
fmt.Println(bty3, err)
fmt.Println(string(bty3))
```

The output is following-

```
map[key:The Knight & Day]
[123 34 107 101 121 34 58 34 84 104 101 32 75 110 105 103 104 116 32 92 117 48 48 50 54 32 68 97 121 34 125] <nil>
{"key":"The Knight \u0026 Day"}
```

What can I do in order to preserve special characters?

Comment: That is preserved, just escaped to prevent problems with various clients. This is valid for JSON.

Comment: I am trying to get hmac value out of it and sending it over network. Other party throws the exception that hmac doesn't match with body.

Comment: Each side needs to check the hmac the data that's sent, not the unencoded data, precisely because of isomorphic changes like this, not to mention possible security issues. However if the remote party isn't doing it right, you will just have to find and replace the escaped strings.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do that? Finding and replacing escaped strings? I won't be knowing what special character I might encounter next.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`encoding/json` docs](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) show the characters that are escaped by default are `<`, `>`, and `&`.

You can use [`strconv.Unquote`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Unquote) like in this answer: [How to convert escape characters in HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36528575/how-to-convert-escape-characters-in-html-tags/36529158#36529158)

Something straightforward like this would work too:

```
bty3 = bytes.Replace(bty3, []byte(`\u003c`), []byte("<"), -1)
bty3 = bytes.Replace(bty3, []byte(`\u003e`), []byte(">"), -1)
bty3 = bytes.Replace(bty3, []byte(`\u0026`), []byte("&"), -1)
```

In the upcoming Go1.7 release, you can turn off the escaping in a `json.Encoder` with `SetEscapeHTML(false)`.

```
mp := map[string]string{"key": "The Knight & Day"}
var buf bytes.Buffer

enc := json.NewEncoder(&buf)
enc.SetEscapeHTML(false)
enc.Encode(mp)

fmt.Println(&buf)
```

Which prints

```
{"key":"The Knight & Day"}
```

Comment: I'd rather use [`strconv.Unquote()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Unquote) like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/oNqqdb1kDB). See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36529158/720999) for more info.

Comment: @kostix: thanks, I new I was forgetting another method for that.